# var dump returns an empty array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Running `var_dump($posts_id)` after the following code brings the data successfully :

```
$posts_pins = DB::table('pins')
        ->join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'pins.post_id')
        ->where('pins.post_id', '=', $posts_id)
        ->get();

            var_dump($posts_id);
            exit();
```

**Output :**

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[199]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=24)
      0 => int 62
      1 => int 63
      2 => int 64
      3 => int 65
      4 => int 66
```

While `var_dump($posts_pins)` brings back an empty array  ... Any ideas ?

Comment: You'd prefer not to go the Eloquent route?

Comment: Is `$posts_id` set and set to something that makes sense? What do you get when you `var_dump(DB::table('pins')->join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'pins.post_id')->where('pins.post_id', '=', $posts_id)->toSql());`? Does that query make sense? What happens when you run that query with the value of `$posts_id`?

Comment: `=` is for testing single values. you're passing in MULTIPLE values, which means you need an `in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `var_dump($posts_id)` I'd say you need a [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses) clause, and possibly a [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-toarray):

```
$posts_pins = DB::table('pins')
            ->join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'pins.post_id')
            ->whereIn('pins.post_id', $posts_id->toArray())
            ->get();
```

The `toArray()` may not be necessary, I'm not sure if the `whereIn` would convert it automatically or not.

The reason is that you're using an array of post ID's while the `where()` method only accepts a single value for comparison, the `whereIn()` accepts an multiple values.

Comment: Worked perfectly ... Thanks